# In Tridion 5.3 which is better to use Event System or Custom Resolver?

Tags: event-system, 5.3, custom-resolver

We have two different publications with shared content: one for the desktop and other for the mobile web.

We would like that if we republish a desktop page the correspondant mobile page gets published too. Moreover, we expect the same behaviour when publishing dynamic components.

I was looking up in the forum, and there are two ways of doing that:

- Event system
- Custom resolver

Which is the best practise for Tridion 5.3?

Answer (score 6):

If those two Publications are Published to the same Target, then you could use a Custom Resolver, if the Targets are different for those Publications, then I think you can only accomplish it through the Event System.

The benefits of using the Event System will be visibility, you add an additional Publish Transaction which shows up in the Publish Queue.

When using a Custom Resolver, you basically see only a single Publish Transaction in the queue, but when you inspect it, you should be able to spot the additional items which are resolved. The benefit of having everything in a single Transaction will be performance, as items inside a Publish Transaction are cached.

So you will have to make the trade-off yourself, using a Custom Resolver will probably give you better performance (depends on a lot of variables), as opposed to the Event System which might visibly make the process more clear when looking at the Publishing Queue.

Comment: Are there Custom resolvers in R5.3 - I thought Tridion 2009 was the first version to have these.

Comment: Ah yeah that's actually a good question, just checked and the `Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Resolving.IResolver` is documented in R5.3 SP1 so it should work.

Comment: Interesting, I guess not many people knew it was there. I remember being surprised when Nuno blogged about them in 2009.

Comment: Yeah actually I was just as surprised, I'm sure besides the method there was nothing documented until 2009 indeed.

Comment: Custom Resolver and Renderers were introduced in 5.3. As usual: documentation was sparse in the initial release and has improved over time.

Answer (score 6):

Given that:

- 5.3 Event Systems are written in COM+/VB6 (or COM-visible .NET assemblies)
- The COM+ Event System has been deprecated in Tridion 2011
- You are likely to upgrade to 2011 or 2013 rather than 2009 on your next system upgrade
- Custom resolvers haven't changed that much since 5.3 and are written with TOM.NET

My preferred option would be to use a Custom Resolver.

Answer (score 5):

Another, less technical, option is to publish from a Blueprint parent and then choose to publish all children.  This assumes that: 
1.  You have a Blueprint parent that contains the Pages / Components to be published
2.  Publishing to child Publications will not publish to other non-desired Publications

If you were using Tridion 2011 (I know you're not currently) and you only wanted to publish these items sometimes and not always, then you could also implement a GUI Extension to show a context menu item saying 'Publish Everywhere'.  This could be done in either the mobile Publication or Desktop.